# MSAccess - Possible to install many versions in parallel (2007, 2010, 2013)?

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to load MANY versions of MS Access on a single machine to permit TESTING of my database in these different envs?

Will these installs STEP on each other (dlls, etc.)?

Saving-down to MDB was unsuccessful.
2013 Runtime attempt also unsuccessful with no clear description of the issue

Any suggestions how to begin to support many versions of access?

Thanks!

Example:  I use an Office file dialog that behaves differently in 2010 than 2013 (was not aware until reported by a user).  I am calling the Office reference, but will move to late bind, but need to confirm it will work properly in v2007 and v2010

Answer (score 1):

If you install the earliest version 1st then with each later version make sure the original does not get removed then it does work. If you put on say Access 2007 before 2003 you may find DLL conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple versions of MS Access installed on the same machine.  I have MS Access 2010 and Access 2000 installed on my machine for testing before I put it in production.

***Office 2010*** resides in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE
```

***Office 2000*** resides in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE
```

You would just use the appropriate executable when you want to use a specific version.  In the above example I am using 64 bit OS.  If you install on 32 bit OS then omit the `(x86)` in the path.

```
Office   is the internal name for Office 2000
Office11 is the internal name for Office 2003
Office12 is the internal name for Office 2007 
Office14 is the internal name for Office 2010
Office15 is the internal name for Office 2013
```

Here is an example Target of a shortcut I use that is secured:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\databases\PDCFE.mdb" /user Enter_User_ID /wrkgrp "F:\PDC\sec.mdw" /pwd ""
```

Comment: Thanks Linger, I'll give that a try.  And report back my success.

Comment: ***Mark Pelletier***, I updated my answer to show the path of a shortcut that I use.  I have a shortcut setup for both of the different versions.